# How to set Timer in JavaFX to execute a display function

Tags: arrays, javafx, timer, javafx-8, chat

I would like to update the view of a pane in a JAVAFX scene each amount of time (example: each 2 seconds) for a chatting window. I have a Display() function that calls an observableList from the db and I would like to call it each 2 seconds so that the user can see the other messages that are coming, not only the ones he's sending (I can obviously call Display() each time the user sends a message, but he won't get the other person's messages).
Anyway searched and I found that you can apparently do that with Timeline so I created this function:

```
   public void RefreshTimer(){
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), e -> {
            DisplayChat(1);
    })
    );
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
}
```

and I'm calling it in the initialize function, but it's making the scene too slow and I think that it's not the right place to call it. So my question is, where do I call this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Timeline` runs the handlers of it's `KeyFrame`s on the application thread responsible for updating the GUI. If you do long-running operations on this thread the GUI becomes unresponsive. Fetch the data on a different thread and use `Platform.runLater` to update the GUI when you've got the information prepared in a way that allows you to update the GUI fast.

```
ListView<String> listView = ...

ThreadFactory tFactory = r -> {
    // use daemon threads
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    return t;
};

// use executor to schedule updates with 2 sec delay in between
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor​(tFactory);
service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
    String[] newMessages = getNewMessagesFromDB(); // long running operation here

    // do fast GUI update
    Platform.runLater(() -> listView.getItems().addAll(newMessages));
}, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```